# Conditional Probability not summing to 1

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say my data looks as follows:

```
object 1: A B C
object 2: C B D
object 3: E B A
object 4: A B E
```

where each object is defined by a combination of 3 characteristics, where characteristics $\in$ {A, B, C, D, E}. The ordering of characteristics does not matter.

Based on this data, I am trying to answer the following:

**Given A is already present for some object, what is the most probable co occurring characteristic?**

While trying to solve this, I ran into some very basic probabilistic errors as noted below:

**Notations**:

- $l_{i}$ = letter i such that $l_{i} \in {A, B, C, D, E}$. So for example: $P(B|A)$ means if A has already occurred in a row, what is the probability of B occurring in the row
- Letters cannot repeat in a row
- The three columns can take values only from {A, B, C, D, E}

Using: $$P(l_{i}) = \frac{count(l_{i})}{Total Count}$$

Gives:

```
P(A) = 3/12  
P(B) = 4/12  
P(C) = 2/12   
P(D) = 1/12   
P(E) = 2/12
```

**Problem 1**: Let's find $P(l_{i}|A)$ using: $$P(l_{i}|A) = \frac{rowcount(l_{i}, A)}{rowcount(A)}$$

```
P(A|A) = 0
P(B|A) = 1 (total 3 rows with A. B occurs in all 3)
P(C|A) = 1/3
P(D|A) = 0
P(E|A) = 2/3
```

This gives $\sum P(l_{i}|A) = 2$ (why?? should sum to 1)

**Problem 2**: Let's find $P(l_{i}, A)$ using: $$P(l_{i}, A) = \frac{count(l_{i}, A)}{ {3 \choose 2} * totalrows} $$

```
In 4 rows with 3 values, there are in total 12 pairs. 
P(A, A) = 0
P(B, A) = 3/12  # count of cooccurrence of A and B divided by total 12 pairs
P(C, A) = 1/12
P(D, A) = 0
P(E, A) = 2/12
```

Now $\sum P(l_{i}, A)$ should be equal to P(A). However, $\sum P(l_{i}, A) = 0.5$, which is 2 times P(A).

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Can you define the events $l_i$ and $A,B,C,D,E$? ( since "$A$ and $A$" is exactly the same event as $A$, $P(A)=P(A,A)$  should always hold. So the problem might be using sloppy notation and then getting mislead by that notation when "plugging into equations".  But it would be easier to find what exactly you are misunderstanding if you explained (in words) what you think you are doing

Comment: Edited the question with notations in plain english

Comment: Does "already occurred" mean there is some time element involved? Or do you by $"P(B \mid A)"$ simply mean the probability of $B$ occurring in a row given that $A$ occurs in the row? How can $P(A)$ be $3/12$ if $A$ means the letter A occurring in a row (how is it not $3/4$)? Also, why do you think these conditional probabilities(?) should sum to $1$?

Comment: It would (in my opinion) be better to define the notations before using them, not just in the end. Furthermore, could you give a plain-words explanation of the interpretation of the three "problems" $P(A),P(B,A),P(B \mid A)$. For example, for the first case (I am guessing here) something like "If one randomly picks a letter from the data, $3$ times out of $12$ it is 'A'". For the latter two cases probably something about randomly picking a row

Comment: There is no time element involved. The question that I am trying to solve is really simple. If I have to 'generate' row 5 in this data, how will I do that? I will first find 'most probable letter', followed by 'next most probable letter given the first probable letter' and so on. The three columns can take values only from {A, B, C, D, E} without duplication.

Comment: done as suggested. Hopefully, the problem is clearer now? If not I can explain on chat and then we could edit it better?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66810/discussion-between-the-wanderer-and-juho-kokkala).

Comment: If A is really a set in a probability space P(A|A) has to equal 1.  You can't define it as 0 and expect the rules of conditional probability to hold. Your notation is a problem.  You define two different events and label them as the same.

Comment: The reason the "probabiities" sum to 2 is that there are 2 other features present whenever A is present.

Answer (score 1):

problem a:

You defined the event $\{l_i|A\}$ as the appearance of $l_1$ in the row if you know A is there as well. 
the problem here is when you sum up all the probability of the occurrences you ignore the fact that 2 events can be at the same time!

for example - in the first row 2 events happened (given A) - $\{B|A,  C|A\}$, so you can't just sum the probability of the events.

how you should do it - you have 2 $l_i$ for each row, so you should count the following events:

$P(\{A,anything\}|A) = 0$
$P(\{A,anything\}|A) = 0$
row 1: A B C
row 2: C B D
row 3: E B A
row 4: A B E

- $P(\{B,C\}|A) = 1/3$
- $P(\{E,B\}|A) = 2/3$

Now these events are independent and therefor the sum should be 1 (and it is)

problem b:
same problem, you count the same event (row 1 for example) twice.

how you should do it:

The overall number of options is 
 - $P(\{B,C\},A) = 1/12$
 - $P(\{E,B\},A) = 2/12$

and again these events are independent, and there sum is indeed 1/4 as it should be

Comment: Cherny: thank you for your answer but I am not sure if I understood correctly !! I also think that I am double counting somewhere, but I am not able to figure out the example you gave

Comment: I added a more specific example -  hope it helps

Comment: Cherny: This seems like a very good explanation. Thank you. Now, in case if I need to find: "Given A is already present for some object, what is the most probable co occurring characteristic?", how would I do that based on this?